# Jenkins email plug-in

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I work on a big project with many other developers and we are using Jenkins as our continues integration tool. We have many automated test suite which are run by Jenkins every day. The question is how can we configure Jenkins to send automatic emails to the specific developer/s who has/have checked in some code which caused test case failure? Can we do it be using the email plug-in?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In "manage Jenkins" add SMTP server and in "configure" of a job, add email address in the "email notification" section. You can add more than one email, separating by a space.

Answer (score 1):

We use Jenkins and a mailing list software (mailman). We have configured Jenkins to send emails (notifications) to a mailing list. Each project have 2 lists with the convention name: ProjectName-build-activity@... and ProjectName-tickets-activity@...

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend the [email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin for more advanced configuration. It has very fine control over whom (commiter,author,default recipients etc.) to send email corresponding to the different possible results(failure,regression etc.).